# NetBeans TomCat Serverlet access though internet

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have my tomcat serverlet project running on my local network and I can access it from any device on the network and it is hosted on my main computer.

In basic steps how do I set it up so I can allow access to the server from any device on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are able to access your project running in Tomcat server because all of the devices are connected via LAN.All of the devices are using the same IP address which is your public IP address for your main computer.So other machines are using submasked version of your public IP address.
So it is not possible to access the server which is actually your PC,you need to buy or rent a server from hosting service providers like Godaddy,HostGator,Google hosting,Amazon AWS etc. Choose your plan from any of these and you are good to go.

Comment: Is it possible to host it on my computer?

Comment: No. Hosting a website means it is hosted via cloud server but modified by you. You can see whatever change/update you do,whatever file you upload and everything. But sorry mate,neither it is hosted in your computer nor it will be using your OS,RAM or memory.